# What is the correct way to handle create-table errors in Android?

Tags: java, android, error-handling, try-catch

For example this snippet

```
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Creating Table: " + createTableStatement);

try {
    db.execSQL(createTableStatement);
}
catch (SQLException e) { //from 'import android.database.SQLException;'
    //do something
}
```

What am I supposed to do exactly in the "do something" part?

Comment: What do you *want* your program to do if it cannot create the table? Log the error and exit the program, maybe?

Comment: That seems reasonable, yes (is that what most people do?)

Comment: What's the correct way to do it? `Log.e(LOG_TAG,  e);`?